# implicit declaration of function'dispatch_get_global_queue'

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this macro in my viewController.m file. I.m new to Xcode btw.

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, 0)
```

I'm getting this error on the line where it says  'kBgQueue', implicit declaration of function  'dispatch_get_global_queue'

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    kLatestKivaLoansURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't it PRIORITY_DEFAULT, not PROPERTY?

Comment: Not sure if this fixes the problem, but I noticed that you have `QUEUE_PROPERTY_DEFAULT` instead of `QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT`. Also, with macros, it's generally a good idea to put the definition in parens

Comment: I find it's generally a good idea not to use them at all :) lack of syntax checking / autocomplete is just one reason.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, but i get another error which i m posting below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got spelling mistakes, I tried and worked fine:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^
```

Works just fine.. :)

**EDIT:**

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
```

is the above line declared in the same file where you are using this? if not import the header where you declared this. :)

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing it out,  yet after i correct my spelling mistake, i get another error saying implicit declaration of function dispatch_get_global_queue is invalid in c99

Comment: @ShawnClarke> Can you share you code? A bit more code?